# See length of value in text box

Tags: javascript, html

I want to be able to type a word into the text box and then click a button underneath which will issue an alert if the number of letters is below 5.

```
Type in words to see how long they are: <input type="text" id="txtBox" name="txtBox" value="banter"/>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try It</button>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById['txtBox'];
        if (x.length < 5) {
        alert('please enter at least 5 characters');
        return false;

        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: You need to use `()` not `[]` i.e. `getElementById('txtBox')`

Comment: because it is method . and we call method by `()` not `[]`

Comment: I think thats correct, but its still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here `x` is an element not a value

So change the `x.length` to `x.value.length`

```html
Type in words to see how long they are: <input type="text" id="txtBox" name="txtBox" value="banter"/>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try It</button>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById('txtBox');
        if (x.value.length < 5) {
          console.log(x.length);
        alert('please enter at least 5 characters');
        }
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your `var x = document.getElementById['txtBox'];` to `var x = document.getElementById('txtbox');`

Answer (score 0):

Two things: functions are called with `()`, not `[]`, and you need to check the `length` of the element's `value` rather that of the element itself.

```
function myFunction() {
    var element = document.getElementById('txtBox');
    if (x.value.length < 5) {
        alert('please enter at least 5 characters');
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, make the following change in your code and it will work:

```
var x = document.getElementById('txtBox').value;
```